# Interaction of function-local enum declaration and ADL

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

The function in namespace X returns an enumerator from a locally defined enum class, via an auto deduced return type.  That return value is then passed to an unqualified function, and on g++ (7.3, 8.2, trunk) it finds the function in namespace X.  On clang, it gives an error for not finding the function.

I assume it has to do with ADL and the question of whether a function-local declared enum is in the function's containing namespace.

Which compiler is right, and why?  (Standard citation appreciated.)

```
namespace X {

      template <typename EnumT>
      EnumT getA(EnumT) {
          return EnumT::A;
      }

      enum class Foo { B, A, C };

      auto getLocalEnumerator() {
          enum class Bar { A, B, C };
          return Bar::C;
      }
}

int main() {
   auto e1 = X::Foo::C;               // unambiguously in namespace X
   auto e2 = X::getLocalEnumerator(); // unsure what namespace this is

   auto a1 = getA(e1);                // obvious use of ADL
   auto a2 = getA(e2);                // clang: error, g++: ADL ok
}
```

live on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/g/w2DhDm

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a clang bug. From [[basic.lookup.argdep]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#2.3):

> The sets of namespaces and classes are determined in the following way: [...] If T is an enumeration type, its associated namespace is the innermost enclosing namespace of its declaration. If it is a class member, its associated class is the member's class; else it has no associated class.

The local enumeration `Bar` has as its associated namespace the innermost enclosing namespace... which is `X`. Unqualified lookup on `getA` finds nothing, so we go ahead and look in all the associated namespaces of all of the arguments - the set of associated namespaces is `{X}`. Lookup there should find `X::getA`.